# Can I get the SqlConnection from SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqldataadapter

Is there any way to get the `SqlConnection` from an `SqlDataAdapter`?

I had expected to find an `SqlDataAdapter.Connection` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `SelectCommand` or whichever command you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

`SqlDataAdapter` has property `SelectCommand` (type of `SqlCommand`) and `SelectCommand` has property `Connection` (type of `SqlConnection`).

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from relevant SqlCommand.

Depending on which one of the is set:

```
        adapter.SelectCommand.Connection;
        adapter.InsertCommand.Connection;
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection;
        adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
....
string connectionString = da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString
```